# Paparazzi file not found exception

Tags: android, gradle, jenkins, snapshot-testing

I have a few tests, we wrote with com.cash.paparazzi
And everything works well on my local machine and another local machines. But on CI, after verify gradle task:

```
./gradlew verifyPaparazziDebug --continue
```

I got this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Exception highlites this row:

```
val paparazzi = Paparazzi( //row with exception
        deviceConfig = DeviceConfig.PIXEL_6.copy(locale = "ru"),
        theme = "BaseTheme"
    )
```

Golden values with images generated successfully, and pushed to repository.
Same git tasks works perfect on clean local machine, so I don't know reason of this issue